# lsof shows lots of same file with a device called 0,0

Tags: lsof

We have begun experiencing outages on a Java application with 'Too many files open' on a soft limit of 2,000. On closer inspection we see hundreds of files that have a device name of 0,0 and are all roughly the same size.

I suspect the device name is significant but can't find anything in the documentation. Any ideas?

```
COMMAND      PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE   SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
java    20381818 vteam 965r  VREG                0,0     459374      0 /PRDdbcls_share (dbcls:/u09)
java    20381818 vteam 966r  VREG                0,0     458866      0 /PRDdbcls_share (dbcls:/u09)
java    20381818 vteam 967r  VREG                0,0     459180      0 /PRDdbcls_share (dbcls:/u09)
```

Thanks,

EddieK

Answer (score 0):

For future reference.

The device number of 0,0 indicates that this is a remote mount so it is not significant here. What was done in the end was to use 'procfiles -n ' and that gave us the open file names. One caveat to this was the command was very slow. If you run it on the host where the files are local it runs mush faster.

I hope this helps someone if they come across the same issue.

EddieK